# 1st order approximation to energy-momentum tensor of gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, linearized-theory

I was studying linearized gravity and this approximation was given without any derivation. It might be clear for others but I'm quite new on GR and I'm not sure how to get this first order approximation and higher order approximations.

**[image]**

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), not a third-party equation editor, to write your math.

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrangian of GR is just $R$. You know that $R$ is a Ricci scalar is a function of the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ and it's derivatives.

All you have have to do is to replace $g_{\mu \nu}$ with $\eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$ . Then you assume that $h_{\mu \nu}$ is small and you ignore all the quadratic terms.
.

Comment: *ignore all the quadratic terms* Then why is every term in that energy-momentum tensor quadratic?

Comment: I think what you have written in the question is the Lagrangian. If you vary it w.r.t. \phi_{\mu \nu}$ you will get the equation of motion (Einstein field equation) which will be first order in $\phi_{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: I am not the OP. I don’t think you have answered the OP’s question. The Lagrangian density is not the energy-momentum tensor. Yes, in linearized gravity the equations of motion are (by definition of “linearized”) first-order in the perturbation around flat spacetime.

Comment: The Lagrangian can have quadratic term. the field equation should be first-order. What he has written is "first order approximation" but the equation is quadratic.  When I looked at the energy-momentum tensor in Weinberg, I see that the variation of that equation in the question yield the a first order field equation.